# Sharepoint 2007: How to create a content page using webservices

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a new content page in SharePoint using SharePoint web services.
Has anyone achieved that ?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are just adding an item to a list, just set the xml fields to the correct ones when updating the item.

If you dont know what fields/properties you need to set, do a get on the first few items to look at the xml

[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/6963fe06-573c-448b-8252-a35c43c8d3d6/](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6963fe06-573c-448b-8252-a35c43c8d3d6/moss-web-services-creating-a-listitem?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)
[http://geekswithblogs.net/WayneMagnum/archive/2008/03/27/sharepoint-list-webservice-to-insert-item.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20200921193822/http://geekswithblogs.net/WayneMagnum/archive/2008/03/27/sharepoint-list-webservice-to-insert-item.aspx)